# How can I make the TypeScript compiler recognize Jest globals only in test files?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, global-variables, tsc, definitelytyped

I'm working on a project using TypeScript and Jest. After I install `@types/jest`, the TypeScript compiler recognizes Jest globals, like `describe` and `test`, in my test files. However, the compiler also regards those globals as available in non-test files. It compiles those files without complaining, but in reality those globals are unavailable when running normally (outside of Jest). Also, my editor (Visual Studio Code) shows Jest globals among the autocomplete options while writing non-test code. This is a nuisance. How can I hide or disable Jest globals in non-test files? Or am I missing a better practice altogether?